# How can I graph a pie chart with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im having trouble graphing a pie chart I cant do it right, Im only able to do a bar graph but a pie chart its a little more complicated. Im a newby with matplotlib, so I have this table and this code.

```
# Ordenamos y tenemos los productos mas comprados por hora. 
orders_hour=products_and_orders.groupby(["order_hour_of_day", "product_name"])["order_id"].count().reset_index()
orders_hour["Porcentaje"]=orders_hour["order_id"]/orders_hour["order_id"].sum()

#Sacamos porcentaje para poder graficar 
orders_hour=orders_hour.nlargest(20, "Porcentaje")
orders_hour
```

```
    order_hour_of_day   product_name    order_id    Porcentaje
233586  10  Banana  40731   0.001256
275816  11  Banana  38455   0.001186
403103  14  Banana  38218   0.001178
445632  15  Banana  38181   0.001177
192707  9   Banana  37980   0.001171
360618  13  Banana  36992   0.001141
487902  16  Banana  36883   0.001137
318182  12  Banana  36206   0.001116
233406  10  Bag of Organic Bananas  31842   0.000982
445451  15  Bag of Organic Bananas  30919   0.000953
275633  11  Bag of Organic Bananas  30914   0.000953
402921  14  Bag of Organic Bananas  30808   0.000950
529804  17  Banana  30701   0.000947
360445  13  Bag of Organic Bananas  30296   0.000934
192528  9   Bag of Organic Bananas  30268   0.000933
318011  12  Bag of Organic Bananas  29443   0.000908
487722  16  Bag of Organic Bananas  29222   0.000901
154712  8   Banana  27420   0.000845
570586  18  Banana  24571   0.000758
529626  17  Bag of Organic Bananas  23820   0.000734
```

How can I do the pie chart the hour_of_day with the product_name?

Answer (score 0):

Well, how would you expect it to look like?
Pie charts are (at least the simple ones) 1-D charts. You could show a pie chart for the product names, and another pie chart for the hour of the day.

Comment: Thabks for answering @ThanosNatsikas Maybe I can do both for better comprenhension.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.pie` takes a list of wedge sizes, and has an argument `labels`, a list ordered the same way as the wedge sizes. For example, `wedgeSizes[0]` would be labeled with `labels[0]`. If I understand you correctly, you can make `wedgesizes` how many orders were done at each hour, and `labels` be a list of the hours. After you use `plt.pie`, use `plt.show()` to display your plot (all of this assuming you've imported matplotlib as plt)

Comment: Thanks for answering, Can you give me an example in code please?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use the Porcentaje data as the basis for your pie chart, then you just need to create the corresponding labels;

`pie_labels = [f"{h}, {p}" for (h,p) in zip(hour_of_day, product_name)]`

`plt.pie(Porcentaje, labels=pie_labels)`

`plt.show()`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, Im trying to do the same but it gives me an error: NameError: name 'order_hour_of_day' is not defined, What Im doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming that you have python lists of the values called Porcentaje, hour_of_day and product_name.  Do you have the data in a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I have my data in a Pandas DF.

Comment: if the dataframe is called `df` then;
`pie_labels = [f"{h}, {p}" for (h,p) in zip(df['hour_of_day'], df['product_name'])]`

`plt.pie(df['Porcentaje'], labels=pie_labels)`

Comment: I dont know what Im doing wrong, but when I run it in only appears some letters.

Comment: @JuanJesus - I added a screenshot of a jupyter notebook.  Hope this helps